# Bash find and replace in a C++ file

Tags: shell-script, sed, replace

I have a C++ script for which I would like to change variable values in some places and then compile, doing this many times for a set of numbers. The following shows my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Rpl_array="30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300 330 360 390 420 450 480 510 540 570 600 630 660 690 720 750 780 810 840 870 900 930 960 1000"
parent_directory="execs_convergence_testing_corrected_robin_condition/phi_0/"
for rpl in ${Rpl_array}; do
        sed -ie "s/R_pl_initial=30.0/R_pl_initial="${rpl}"/g" iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp
        sed -ie "s/Rpl_30/Rpl_"${rpl}"/g" iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp
        g++ -std=c++0x iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp -o ${parent_directory}/Rpl_${rpl}.exe
    done
```

As can be seen, I use `sed`  twice to try to first replace a variable value and then change a string. I then compile for the change, subsequently running over all the values in rpl. However, this code does not work for me. I wonder what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: seems to me like you have extra double-quotes; try just `sed "s/R_pl_initial=30.0/R_pl_initial=$rpl/g"`, for example

Comment: It does not seem to work. When the shell script finishes running, am I supposed to see the last change in the file itself?

Comment: well, I accidentally removed your `-i` option, but otherwise - yes

Comment: why not just modify your C++ program to take the Rpl value from a command-line argument?  or a config file?  recompiling just to change a single variable seems excessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've written the script, the changes are made to the main C++ source file; thus the first time it runs, you replace 30.0 with 30, and the second time it runs, the first `sed` won't find anything to replace...

The following should work (also fixing the quoting issue):

```
#!/bin/bash

Rpl_array="30 60 90 120 150 180 210 240 270 300 330 360 390 420 450 480 510 540 570 600 630 660 690 720 750 780 810 840 870 900 930 960 1000"
parent_directory="execs_convergence_testing_corrected_robin_condition/phi_0/"
for rpl in ${Rpl_array}; do
    sed -ie "s/R_pl_initial=30.0/R_pl_initial=${rpl}/g" iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp
    sed -ie "s/Rpl_30/Rpl_${rpl}/g" iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp
    g++ -std=c++0x iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp -o ${parent_directory}/Rpl_${rpl}.exe
    sed -ie "s/R_pl_initial=${rpl}/R_pl_initial=30.0/g" iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp
    sed -ie "s/Rpl_${rpl}/Rpl_30/g" iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp
done
```

There are other ways to go about it; you could use a temporary C++ file and compile that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify the file `iron_ablation_phi_nonzero_checking.cpp` in each iteration of the loop, but your `sed` commands replace the *initial* values of some variables by new values. That works only for the first iteration; when you enter the second iteration of the loop, the file contains already the result of the first replacement, rather than the initial value, and therefore the `sed` commands fail.